# When generating an angular component where does the src/app prefix come from

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng-generate

I'm probably bad at google for not finding this but here it goes.

When generating a component with `ng generate` where does the `src/app` path prefix come from and how can I change it?

I'm talking about `src/app` in the following image.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it in your angular.json file, the property is `sourceRoot` eg:

```
"sourceRoot": "projects/myproject/src",
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find it inside angular.json file. For better understanding please follow official Angular guide

https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should go to path you want to create the component

ex

cd desired-path

ng g c desired-component-name